# PHP MYSQL Query AS greater issue

Tags: php, mysql

I need AS query but example:

rat ='10' or rat >='10' for this query;

```
$minimalEntry = mysql_query("SELECT author,count(id) AS rat 
                               FROM sds_posts 
                           GROUP BY author 
                           ORDER BY rat ASC 
                              LIMIT 0,20");
```

thank you..

Comment: Do you just mean you need to add a WHERE or HAVING clause?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need `HAVING` clause:

```
SELECT author, COUNT(id) AS rat 
FROM sds_posts 
GROUP BY author 
HAVING COUNT(id) >= 10
ORDER BY rat ASC 
  LIMIT 0,20
```

Comment: +1 In this statement, the alias `rat` can be referenced in the `HAVING` clause (as well as the `ORDER BY` clause).  This can be very convenient when it's a complex aggregate expression that would otherwise need to be repeated.

Comment: @spencer7593 Aliases referenced in the HAVING clause are a MySQL deviation from the standard. Not that it's bad but I tend to avoid this.

Comment: good point. This is one deviation in MySQL that I do tend to take advantage of. (Interestingly, Teradata also provides a deviation from the standard, in that they allow for the keyword `NAMED` in place of the keyword `AS` preceding a column alias, and a `NAMED` alias is available for reference elsewhere in the statement where the named expression would otherwise need to be repeated. And I take advantage of this deviation as well.)

Answer (score 1):

Just add a WHERE condition.

```
$minimalEntry = mysql_query("SELECT author,count(id) AS rat 
                             FROM sds_posts 
                             WHERE count(id)  >= 10 
                             GROUP BY author 
                             ORDER BY rat ASC 
                             LIMIT 0,20"
                           );
```

EDIT: this is wrong. You need the HAVING clause in this query.

Comment: Here you go, my last vote for today. Enjoy your [fancy usercard](http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/established-user). :)

Answer (score 1):

I would use an inner select to avoid doubling the count aggregate:

```
SELECT author, rat
FROM
(
    SELECT author, count(id) AS rat
    FROM sds_posts
) 
WHERE rat >= 10
ORDER BY rat
LIMIT 0,20
```